# Firebase is allowing Unregistered user to log in

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make a notes app, on which i am trying to make user login based on "email and password" method of firebase. I have successfully designed a way to register user with email and password which is also shown on firebase console. Although, when trying to login by using "SignInWithEmailAndPassword" method, i am able to login with unregistered emails and password.

Here is the code,i am having problem in:

```
 onPressed: () async {
    try {
      final checkuser =
          auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: Email!, password: Password!);
      if (checkuser != null) {
        
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, MainScreen.id);
      }
      
    } catch (e) {
      showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
            AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Login Alert'),
          content: Text(
              e.toString()),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () =>
                  Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  },
```

Code is running good, there is no syntax error. Only Problem is unregistered users are also allowed to login.

Comment: You can refer to the official documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/password-auth

Comment: What are the Email! and Password! fields that you are passing? are they dynamic and changing upon every 'Go' call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was a dumb question, documentation has changed, i guess. The tutorial i followed for creating app has the problematic code that i have written above but as i was going through documentation of firebase thanks to a comment on the questions, i figured out the problem, so here is the updated code:

```
 onPressed: () async {
                            try {
                              final checkuser =
                                  await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                      email: Email!, password: Password!);
                              Navigator.pushNamed(context, MainScreen.id);
                            } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                              showDialog<String>(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                    AlertDialog(
                                  title: const Text('Login Alert'),
                                  content: Text(e.toString()),
                                  actions: <Widget>[
                                    TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () =>
                                          Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
                                      child: const Text('OK'),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                          },
```

Thanks for everyone help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to Firebase login:

```
    class Root extends StatelessWidget {
      const Root({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: Authentication.onAuthStateChanged,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Center(child: Text('No internet connection!'));
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return const HomePage();
            }
            return const LoginPage();
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is in the code OP shared, and *how* this change would fix that problem?

Comment: Hi, I'm unsure what your problem is. I need more info about the parameters I mentioned in my comment above. I am marely proposing an elegant solution you might want to consider.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured it out, well it was embarrasing tbh.

Comment: There is no such thing as a dumb question! I write a lot of questions myself and there's no shame in doing that. 